# How to select a value from drop down in a cell of MS Excel with keyboard?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Is there any way to select the value from a drop down list in excel by using only keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> (+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> also works).
Then you can use the arrow keys (<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> also work) to move around the selection and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select an entry.

Edit: works on autofilters, too.

Comment: Alt + Down Arrow opens the list.  Then up/down arrows move to the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Use the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to select an item from the dropdown, as the enter key finishes entering data in the cell.