# Select value from formula completion drop down list, by keyboard

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to select a value with the keyboard from a drop down list that is shown when composing a formula?

[image: Select from drop down list]

I tried the following:

- Enter
- Space
- Alt-up or Alt-down [as suggested here](https://superuser.com/questions/178923/how-to-select-a-value-from-drop-down-in-a-cell-of-ms-excel-with-keyboard)
- F4 (the default close-up command for combo boxes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try <kbd>TAB</kbd> instead... ;)

Answer (score 7):

Please find below link from Allen Wyatt's website.

http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010181_Selecting_a_Suggestion_with_the_Keyboard.html

I was also looking for this also before but didn't bother to find out until I've read this post.

The answer is "TAB" key after you have selected the function/formula from the list by arrow down/up key.